# Connect application Java to websphere MQ

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

please I want to create a class Java that permit me to send a message for a queue manager(local queue)
can you help me ? thanks !!

Comment: All the detail in the comments below should have been in the question from the beginning.  IBM provides sample programs do do what you are asking. For the question to be relevant to Stack Overflow, you need to tell us what you've done and how it didn't work.  That includesa version of the QMgr, version of the client, the fact that you got authorization errors, etc. Voting to close unless the question is updated with sufficient detail as per SO guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

There are sample programs that come with a MQ installation.  Check \tools\wmqjava\samples folder.  MQSample.java is a good place to start. JMS Samples are in \tools\jms\samples folder.

Check [IBM Knowledgecentre](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030520_.htm?lang=en) for further documentation.

If you are using MQ7.1 and above, take a look at [Morag's channel authentication blog post on developerworks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/blocked_by_chlauth_why?lang=en).  Also, you have to set authorization for a particular user against the queue and queue manager. Check [T.Rob's excellent article on authorization](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1003_mismes/1003_mismes.html).

Comment: yes I tried it 
but it's not working 
for example I use this class SampltePTP
when I compile it I have this error (but it's working in a consoole)

Comment: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: Authentication security provided to the queue manager QM 'with the connection mode' Client 'and the hostname' localhost (1414) 'was invalid.
Check if the user name and password provided are correct in the waiting queue manager to which you connect.
Inner exception (s):

Comment: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: Authentication security provided to the queue manager QM 'with the connection mode' Client 'and the hostname' localhost (1414) 'was invalid.
Check if the user name and password provided are correct in the waiting queue manager to which you connect.
Inner exception (s):
com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: The WebSphere MQ call failed with the completion code '2' ('MQCC_FAILED'); pattern '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
FAILURE

Comment: Can you post your codes? It seems you are trying to connection to a local MQ on default port 1414.